# Highchart : Add data padding for left stepped area last point

Tags: highcharts

When last value in left stepped area is different from previous one it is hard to see it. (we just see a line along the end of the chart)

[image]

Demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/x2qf5wuy/1/

```
$("#container").highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            step: 'left'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: "Example 1",
        data: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }, {
        name: "Example 2",
        data: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
    }]
});
```

There is a way in highchart to add an artificial padding to data series so that the user can see the last point ?

Wanted result :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a point with the same `y` value as the last series point and use the `setExtremes` method to show only the wanted part of the `area`:

```
chart: {
    type: 'area',
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var series = this.series[1],
                lastPoint = series.data[series.data.length - 1];

            series.addPoint({
                x: lastPoint.x + 100,
                y: lastPoint.y
            }, false);
            this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, lastPoint.x + 0.5);
        }
    }
},
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/54a6jdgy/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's not about the zero value, but about the last point of the serie. I've added a picture to show wanted result

Comment: Hi @fabien-michel, Sorry for missunderstanding and thakns for the image. You can add a point and change the axis extremes: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3ebvta1h/

Comment: It work as expected, thank for your answer ! I was hoping for less "hacky" solution which not involve modifying serie's data

Comment: In my real use case, the graph can display up to many thousand of points in a serie which mean that "adding a point" can not be enough in some cases / user screen, etc... I was hoping for a solution taking care of that

Comment: @fabien-michel, Every series in Highcharts represents data, so to change the series graphic it is best to change the data. It seems that this is the only solution, but you can customize it to suit more of your cases. For example, you can change the `x` value of added point so that it never appears on a user screen: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/huxfvdt8/